# Should two-word tags be separated by dash?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[This question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/34/35) has tag [currencyexchange](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currencyexchange), shouldn't be [currency-exchange](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency-exchange)?

I've tried to rename it, but it failed to do that.

Comment: please also retag tail (was tailemission) privatekey and messagesigning as: "tail-emission" "private-key" and "message-signing"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the convention is to hyphenate tags that use multiple words. I edited this tag to read [currency-exchange](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency-exchange).

Answer (score 7):

Based on this the fullnode tag should become full-node

Answer (score 4):

Yes; and the same applies to:

- [fullnode](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullnode)
- [coldstorage](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldstorage)
- [tailemission](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tailemission)