# tail-emission tag modification

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I disagree with the edit that a changed "tailemission" tag to "tail". Instead I agree with the logic here:

[Should two-word tags be separated by dash?](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-two-word-tags-be-separated-by-dash)

Applying the above rule, "tailemission" should become "tail-emission" instead

We should try to remain consistent sometimes looking for similar tags on other Stacks for guidance where applicable

please also retag privatekey and messagesigning as "private-key" and "message-signing"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there was also an [emission] tag, I assume someone inadvertently typed [tail] [emission] as two words instead of one.

No problem, I renamed all the intervening tags so we only have one [tail-emission](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tail-emission) tag. Text completion should take care of the rest:

<kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> → <kbd>tail-emission</kbd>